# Entity Framework Core - How To Access Context.Database.Migrate()

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0

I am just getting started with EF Core and Net Core in general an ran into a problem I could not find any answers for.

I am working on a console application that uses a SQLite database for storage. I am testing things right now and working with the context works fine. My example program below runs fine. Note that I did use migrations to create the database initially.

Now eventually when I finish this App I want to make sure that the database exists. As read in other posts this should be done with `ctx.Database.Migrate()`. I cannot access this method yet however. So my question is what do I have to do to access it? Am I missing a package that adds an extension method? Do I need to configure more things?

Please excuse this very basic question but I could not find anything regarding this. So if I just don't know where to look I would also be glad about a reading recommendation.

```
using System;
using MyLog.NetCore.Models;
using MyLog.NetCore.DataAccess;

namespace MyLog.NetCore
{
    internal class Program
    {
        #region Private Methods

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var ctx = new MyLogContext())
            {
                ctx.Add(new PartialLogEntry { PartialLogEntryID = 1, StartDateTime = 1, Title = "Test" });
                var count = ctx.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine($"{count} changes saved to database!");

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("All partial lof entries in database:");
                foreach (var entry in ctx.PartialLogEntries)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"ID: {entry.PartialLogEntryID}\tStart: {entry.StartDateTime}\tTitle: {entry.Title}");
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        #endregion Private Methods
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many EF Core methods are implemented as extension methods. So to make them available, this first thing you need is:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

This particular method is defined in `RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions` residing in the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` assembly, so make sure you are referencing it.

Comment: Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational -Version 2.0.1 For more Refrence